# Why is function in then not receiving object

Tags: javascript

I understand the notion of Promises, but something seems not to be completely clear to me.

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> .......
<div id="map"></div>
<script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLE_API&callback=initialize"
        async></script>
</body>
</html>

<script src="js/currentRoute.js"></script>
```

I have the following JS code:

```
async function getCurrentUserCoordinates() {
    console.log("Am getCurrentUserCoordinates")

    const url = baseUrl + `/SOME_REST_API_URL`;

    if (checkAdminOrTechRights(parseToken(getToken()))) {
        await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${getToken()}`
            },
        })
            .then((response) =>
                response
                    .json()
            )
            .then(terminals => {
                let locations = [];
                terminals.forEach(terminal => {
                    locations.push({
                        lat: terminal.latitude,
                        lng: terminal.longitude,
                        name: terminal.name,
                        location: terminal.location
                    })
                })
                console.log(locations) // ALL IS PRINTING OK HERE
                return locations;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            })
    }
}

function initMap(locations) {
    console.log("Am initMap")
    console.log("printing locations: " + locations) // I HAVE UNDEFINED HERE
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 0.123123123123, lng: 0.123123123123},
    });
    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "",
        disableAutoPan: true,
    });

    const markers = locations.map((terminal, i) => {
        const label = `${terminal.name}, ${terminal.location}`;
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: terminal,
            label,
        });

        marker.addListener("click", () => {
            infoWindow.setContent(label);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        return marker;
    });

    new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({markers, map});
}


async function initialize() {
    console.log("Am initialize")
    getCurrentUserCoordinates()
        .then(locations => initMap(locations))
        .then(() => console.log("Am done"))
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error("ERROR!!! " + err);
        })
}
```

I have the following logs:

```
Am initialize

currentRoute.js:2 Am getCurrentUserCoordinates

currentRoute.js:28 (26) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {lat: 1.123123123, lng: 1.123123123, name: 'TERM-0001', location: 'LOCATION'}1: {lat: 1.123123123, lng: 1.123123123, name: 'TERM-0099', location: 'LOCATION'}2: ............ 25: {lat: 1.123123123, lng: 1.123123123, name: 'TERM-0023', location: 'LOCATION'}length: 26[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

currentRoute.js:37 Am initMap

currentRoute.js:38 printing locations: undefined
```

So in my view initMap() has to be called when the getCurrentUserCoordinates() returns the result (locations). Inside the functions am getting locations and as seen on the logs they are printed. But the locations are passed as undefined inside the initMap functions.

What am I not getting here?

Thank you.

Comment: `getCurrentUserCoordinates` does not `return` anything

Comment: return locations - so this is not doing anything?

Comment: That's returning from the `terminals => {…}` function

Comment: @matua no, that is inside another method. It does not return from the outewr method `getCurrentUserCoordinates`. Hint: Dont mix async/await and `then` it leads to confusion. Use one pattern or the other

Comment: Wy would you use both `async/await` and `.then()`? Either use the Promise-style syntax `.then()` or the syntactic sugar `async/await`, not both together

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code was that you were calling `return` from inside a nested function within `then` which you had assumed would return from the outer method `getCurrentUserCoordinates` but that is not the case.

Your functionality can be hugely simplified by not mixing async/await with `then` - the former is easier to manage. The code also benefits from replacing the clunky array + `forEach` with a simple `map` over the array.

```
async function getCurrentUserCoordinates() {
    console.log("Am getCurrentUserCoordinates")

    const url = baseUrl + `/SOME_REST_API_URL`;

    if (checkAdminOrTechRights(parseToken(getToken()))) {
      try{
        const result = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${getToken()}`
            },
        });
        const terminals = await result.json();
        let locations = terminals.map( terminal => ({
                lat: terminal.latitude,
                lng: terminal.longitude,
                name: terminal.name,
                location: terminal.location
        }))
        console.log(locations) // ALL IS PRINTING OK HERE
        return locations;
       }
       catch(err){
        console.error(err);
       }        
    }
}
```

* Note the `return locations` in this code is now in the outer scope of the method itself, however as the method is `async` it actually returns a `Promise` so you must await it later on (see below). H/T @JeremyThille

The same is true later in your code

```
async function initialize() {
    console.log("Am initialize")
    try{
        const currentUserCoords = await getCurrentUserCoordinates();
        const locations = initMap(currentUserCoords);
        console.log("Am done"))
    }
    catch(err){
        console.error("ERROR!!! " + err);
    }
}
```

Comment: also `locations = terminals.map(...)` instead of `.forEach( push() )`

Comment: @JeremyThille I was just making exactly that update :)

Comment: I was about to suggest exactly this other update too :D

Comment: @matua To be noted though, `return locations` does return something (in this answer), but as a Promise, not as a value, because the function is marked as `async`. It will need to be awaited : `const coordinates= await getCurrentUserCoordinates()` (as Jamiec correctly specified)

Comment: @JeremyThille the top level `fetch` was never returned, if it were your comment would be correct

Comment: I mean `return locations` in _your_ code, not OP's. It does return something in yours, it does not in theirs.

Comment: aaah right I misunderstood

Comment: My bad, it was indeed misleading

Comment: Guys, thank you so much for your help. I now got it and you are an awesome community!

Comment: @matua you're most welcome.